# Consuming a service with Basic Auth through API proxy

Tags: wso2-choreo

I'm in the process of testing access to a basic service deployed on Choreo, which is secured with authorization. I've set up an API proxy for the service on Choreo, and I possess multiple API keys for both the service and the proxy. What is the recommended approach for testing the service through the proxy while considering the existence of multiple API keys?